# Very rare failures to lock availability when leasing pull tasks

Tags: python, google-app-engine, task-queue

I am building a python application that has multiple works lease tasks from the same pull queue. When leasing tasks, I carefully set `lease_seconds` to make sure the worker has enough time to finish the job and delete the task before the lease expires.

[GAE's document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/pull/leasing-pull-tasks) said

> Leasing a task makes it unavailable for processing by another worker,
>   and it remains unavailable until the lease expires.

For me it is true in most time. However, in very rare cases (once per hundreds leases),  one task may be leased by another worker before its previous lease expires. It seems the backend service failed to lock its availability.

How can prevent such things happening?

**Update:**

I just found my worker actually tried to delete the problematic task before it is re-leased.
Here is my observations so far. Not sure if all conclusions are valid, I will keep watching it.

1. It happens if there are two (almost) concurrent .add() requests on the
   same queue.
2. It happens even if there is only one worker pulling from queue.
3. Say we added task A then B concurrently, it can happen on either one. <del>always happens on task A (The one that is firstly leased)</del>
4. Below are timestamps(in mm:ss format) of the latest occurrence

   - 24:04: Add task A and B
   - 24:12: Lease a task (get task A, ETA=30:43)
   - 25:51: Finished task A and delete it from queue
   - 25:57: Lease next task (get task B, ETA=32:27)
   - 27:16: Finished task B and delete it from queue
   - 27:20: Lease next task (**get task A again!**)

Comment: How did you identify these events?

Comment: @DanCornilescu I have a ndb model that records all events on each task, including when it is created, when it is firstly leased, who is working on it, when to expire, when it is actually done, etc. The id of such records is passed to task as parameter. So when I successfully leased a task, I check its lease history,  and occasionally find it is re-leased before its last lease expires.

Comment: If a worker leases a task but fails to delete it before the lease expires the task will be handed to another worker, with a new lease time. Can you check if this wasn't the case?

Comment: @DanCornilescu, it is not my case. However I just found the Task.eta property makes more sense than I knew. I will monitor this property for a few days and share by observation later.

Comment: Hi! Did the Task.eta monitoring yield some result?

Comment: @GuillermoCacheda I posted my observations so far. Not sure if all is valid, will keep watching it.

Comment: So, with this one I'm suspecting about two things. First is the implementation of the lease, IDs and such, as this is by no means how it should be behaving. Second is the "tried to delete" part. Can you confirm that the task is being deleted correctly? Also, it would be useful if you could provide the timestamps with miliseconds.

Comment: I am trying to reproduce the error in a dedicated test app. I will post the code to github when caught  an error.

Comment: Also please provide the updates here.

Comment: So far I have run ~1300 tasks with dedicated test app, not catch an error yet. I need revise my code.